# Spring bean definition : ArrayList of String array

Tags: java, spring

How can I define a Spring bean in an xml config file matching this attribute ?

```
private List<String[]> durations;
```

I've different things, but none of them seems to work - I'm getting exception from the parser.

Thank you !

Comment: What did you try that isn't working, and what version of Spring?

Comment: Sorry guys I've been away for a long time ! I'm not anymore on this project but I'll try what you've told me and let you know. Thanks anyway for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a `<list>` in `<list>` in the spring application context. A `<list>` is converted by spring to either a real `java.util.List` or an array.

```
    <property name="durations">
        <list>
            <list>
                <value>abc</value>
                <value>def</value>
            </list>
            <list>
                <value>abc2</value>
                <value>def2</value>
            </list>
        </list>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <bean name="test" class="Test">
    <property name="values" value="hugo,emil"/>
</bean>
```

Spring should carryout the conversion for you if you seperate the values with comma's.

values is a String[] array

Answer (score 0):

Try without generic type : `private List durations;`